# Aeron spy subscriptions and flow control

Tags: aeron

I want to record a publication with `SourceLocation.LOCAL` to benefit from the zero-copy spy archive subscriptions. However the documentation says that spy subscriptions do not factor in receiver flow control strategies.

Assume there is only one other subscriber besides the archive, that it's a remote subscriber and that it's slow. Since it's the only one taken into account for flow control, it will cause back-pressure even with `fc=tagged,g:42/1` on the publication and `gtag=42` on the archive subscription. But if the archive subscription was taken into account in flow control, since it is likely faster the laggy subscriber could be left behind as I intend.

Is it possible to get both the optimized zero-copy spy subscriptions for recording and the removal of subscribers that lag behind the archive's spy subscription?

Comment: Why use tagged flow control when you are happy for the remote subscribers to be left behind? You could use max flow control and have spies simulate connection set to true.

Comment: @MartinThompson Thanks for helping with this. From [the GitHub wiki](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/wiki/Flow-and-Congestion-Control): "A subscription which spies [...] on an outgoing local UDP publication is not involved in receiver based flow control for min, max, or tagged."

Comment: Yes, spies are not used in receiver based flow control but they can simulate a connection when no receivers are present.

Comment: @MartinThompson What prompted me to ask this question is that I have an archive recording a Publication with a spy subscription, and a remote client subscribing normally to the data from said Publication. The remote client is slow, the archive isn't, and `Publication#offer` returns `BACK_PRESSURED`. There's no flow control configuration anywhere so the default max flow control strategy is used. This contradicts the notion that (fast) spy subscriptions under max flow control will prevent back-pressure.

Comment: What you are asking for is outside the standard offering. You could build your own custom flow control or contract out the development.